# Starting activity after receive fcm notification on lock screen in Android Q

Tags: java, android, push-notification

For my application, I need to realize behaviour like WhatsApp, show my application above the lock screen when a device is locked, and I did it successfully in android versions below Android Q. To do that I grant `Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION`. Does anybody know how to do it without `SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW permission`? For push notification I use fcm.

My code:

```
private void tryWakeUp() {
        try {

            String ns = getApplicationContext().getPackageName();
            String cls = ns + ".MainActivity";
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Class.forName(cls));
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
            intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
            intent.putExtra("foreground", true);
            intent.putExtra("incoming_call", true);

            PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getApplicationContext()
                    .getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);

            PowerManager.WakeLock wl1 = pm.newWakeLock(
                    PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP |
                            PowerManager.ON_AFTER_RELEASE |
                            PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK,
                    "wl1"
            );
            wl1.acquire(10000);

            Log.d(TAG, "try wake up");

            startActivity(intent);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.w(TAG, "Failed to open application on message receive", e);
        }
    }
```

This code executes after I receive data push notification.

Comment: Try to use my old answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58723440/how-can-i-listen-a-incoming-video-call-from-my-app-using-opentok/58723705#58723705

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work for me

Answer (score 1):

Use `setVisiblity()` from `NotificationBuilder` added in API level 21 Android 5.0) :

```
notificationBuilder.setVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC);
```

> public NotificationCompat.Builder setVisibility (int visibility)
>   Sets Notification.visibility.
>
> Parameters
>   **visibility    int**: One of **Notification.VISIBILITY_PRIVATE** (the default), **Notification.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC**, or **Notification.VISIBILITY_SECRET**.

Answer (score 0):

WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED has deprecated in Android Q. Instead you can use Activity.setShowWhenLocked(true) and Activity.setTurnScreenOn(true) in onCreate of Activity to show activity in lock screen.

Comment: This flag works if activity was on the screen before I lock screen. But if the activity isn't visible and I lock screen and after that send push notification then nothing happens. ```startActivity``` doesn't work