# How to launch app or showing calling screen when received call from admin portal in case of background/killed?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, opentok, videocall

How can i show calling screen with accept/reject button when my app will receive call from admin side(back-end) when app is in background or killed state. Is their any way to achieve this? My app requirement is,it can only receive Video Call from back-end, i'm using OpenTok for video call. App is working fine when it is in visible state. I'm able to show calling screen with both buttons. But when app is in background or killed than unable to handle this. I'm getting push when call initiated from admin side.

Comment: Check my old answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58723440/how-can-i-listen-a-incoming-video-call-from-my-app-using-opentok/58723705#58723705

Comment: @JohnLe it's not called if my app is in background.

Comment: Try to add the permission: `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />`

Comment: @JohnLe already added sir, i think its may be API level deprecation issue. currently i'm testing in api level 25.

Comment: It works well on my side. Sr, I don't know why